# IdentityServer4 as 3 Tier (Presentation, Application and Db)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, identityserver4

We are starting to use IdentityServer as a centralize peice for User Authentication/Authroization + Securing our Apis and Applications.
We have few applications written using various frameworkks like WebForm Application, Desktop Application, .NetCore Mvc Web App, AngularJS Spa based Application and few apis built using MVC (.net Core).

We are starting with 2 Apis and AngularJS Application (using Implicit flow) and we will potentially migrate user from existing Database to IDServer Db.

I was told by our Enterprise Architect that we want to be able deploy IDServer in three tier. Presentation, Application and DB.

My Understanding is IDserver is nicely integrated with IdentityDbContext, ConfigurationDbContext and OperationDbContext.

I am not sure how can I break IdServer in three layers and extract application layer out of it for it to be able to deploy to Application Server expose via Http? Also IDServer expose lot of Http Endpoints as well like token/Connect, /.last-wellknow-configuration and /userinfo... so I am confused if it's good idea to even break that into 3 tier?

Comment: I've split off the database portion at this point into it's own assembly for the simple reason it will allow me to do user mgmt functions that are outside the scope of IdS.  As for the layers above the database, I haven't tried to break those apart yet as I haven't seen a ton of benefit in doing so because I am using the implementations you talked about (IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity and IdentityServer4.EntityFramework).   Interested to see what others have to say about this question.

Comment: A typical application built using the IdentityServer4 framework will be a 3 tier application so your architect's request is somewhat strange. I guess my question is what makes you think it's not 3 tier already?

Comment: because IdentityServer Project direct talk to DB using EF.. using IdentityDbContext and ConfigurationDbContext... There is no Layer deployed between Presentation and DB....

Comment: @hanz The IdentityServer4 framework has no hard dependency on EF - that's implemented as a separate library that implements the various stores that IDS4 requires which is then resolved at runtime by the dependency resolver. You're free to implement your own persistence layer any way you see fit, you'd just need to support the models defined by IDS4.
Given that is the case what does the solution you have in mind look like?

Comment: @mackie I have been doing some digging in to this... Yes. There are various stores IdServer4 requires. Possible solution could be than write an api layer deployed to App Tier which will directly talk to IdentityServer Db Tables and then use HttpClient on the presention tier where I will add custom implementation of IClientStore, IResourceStore, IUserStore, IPersistedGrantStore and other IdServer store interfaces which will talk to the underlying api. I have not seen any examples of something like that... and not sure if there are benefits?

Comment: @hanz I don't see any benefit to adding another physically separate tier in this instance - the framework and application are already insulated from the details of the persistence store and since the DB for your identity server should be private the Identity server application itself should be the the gatekeeper to that data. I.e. if anything else needs access to it then it should expose its own API rather. This API could be part of the same process or a separate microservice which uses the same library to talk to the persistence store.